# Looping two actions

Tags: python, selenium

How would I go about looping these two actions only in the code.

`driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='skipAnimation']").click() time.sleep(1) driver.find_element_by_xpath("// *[@id='openAnother']").click()`

I don't want to loop the whole code I want these two codes to repeat until I stop it

Comment: If you want to loop on only those two lines, loop on only them? What are you trying?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does Python know a block of code is in a loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32176128/how-does-python-know-a-block-of-code-is-in-a-loop) Note: If you don't have a number of times you want to iterate for a `while` loop might be more suitable for you.

Comment: So something like while statement 1 and 2 are true keep doing the action ?

Comment: Didn't you say "_until I stop it_"? You need some way to tell it to stop. You might want to go through a python tutorial first, you seem to be asking pretty basic questions.

Answer (score 0):

Your goal is not really clear: "I don't want to loop the whole code I want these two codes to repeat until I stop it".
Do you expect to end the loop 'manually'?
If so, then you can ask for user input in Python with `input()`.
If my understanding of the problem is correct, you want to run your two functions until you decide to manually stop them running?
I believe a while loop could be used for this task.
You have different options depending if you want to press a key at each iteration, or if you want it to loop until you press a specific key.
Press at each iteration:

```
while True:    # infinite loop
    user_input = input("Want to continue? ")
    if user_input == "No":
        break  # stops the loop
    else:
        # do whatever computations you need
        driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='skipAnimation']").click() 
        time.sleep(1) 
        driver.find_element_by_xpath("// *[@id='openAnother']").click()
        print('looping')
```

Now, if you want it to constantly run, until you press a key, there are two options:

```
while True:
    try:
        # do whatever computations you need
        driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='skipAnimation']").click() 
        time.sleep(1) 
        driver.find_element_by_xpath("// *[@id='openAnother']").click()
        print('looping')
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        break
```

Or

```
import msvcrt
while True:
    # do whatever computations you need
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='skipAnimation']").click() 
    time.sleep(1) 
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("// *[@id='openAnother']").click()
    print('looping')

    if msvcrt.kbhit():
        break
```

But pay attention to the behavior if you're in a notebook.